# What code do I add where on my site to differentiate between roots in Google Analytics?

Tags: html, google-analytics

Google analytics shows me the report for the root of my site (`/`), however, there are two possible roots. One for public users (and google bot), one for logged in users (like Facebook, for example).

Can I add some code, anywhere to my HTML, so that in Google Analytics I can see those two pages differentiated?

I don't want to code two different links for those two pages, for simple reasons:

- I don't want/need to index the inside of my site, so I don't care that google bot doesn't know about it
- I don't want my public main page to be domain.com/something
- I don't want my 'logged in' main page to be domain.com/something-else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a special url for logged in users as a parameter to your track pageview call via serverside code (or a javascript funktion).

Example (assuming you use the asynchronous code):

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/root_loggedind']);
```

Even though the url "/root_loggedind" does not physically exist it will register in your reports. The root for "normal" users will still register as simply "/".